# `C++ concurrency in Action` chapter 4 doubts

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, concurrency

I am currently reading `C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd edition`, page 111 (Chapter 4). It's a somewhat long question.

So the author is showing how to write a good concurrent version of a function that processes user logins.
This is the first, sequential snippet:

```cpp
void process_login(std::string const& username,std::string const& password)
{
  try {
    user_id const id=backend.authenticate_user(username,password);
    user_data const info_to_display=backend.request_current_info(id);
    update_display(info_to_display);
  } catch(std::exception& e){
    display_error(e);
  }
}
```

[1] The first attempt is to use `std::async` so that the whole process is done in a new thread, such as:

```cpp
std::future<void> process_login(const std::string& username, const std::string& password)
{
  return std::async(std::launch::async,[=]() {
    try {
      user_id const id = backend.authenticate_user(username, password);
      user_data const info_to_display = backend.request_current_info(id);
      update_display(info_to_display);
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
      display_error(e);
    }
 });
}
```

However, according to the author, [1] is not so good because "*With plain std::async, you could punt it all to a background thread like the next listing, **but that would still block that thread, consuming resources while waiting for the tasks to complete***"

[2] Therefore the author shows a new way to do the processing, by using continuations and chaining tasks:

```cpp
std::experimental::future<void> process_login(
 const std::string& username, const std::string& password)
{
  return spawn_async([=]() {
    return backend.authenticate_user(username, password);
  }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_id> id) {
    return backend.request_current_info(id.get());
  }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_data> info_to_display) {
    try {
      update_display(info_to_display.get());
    } catch(std::exception& e){
      display_error(e);
    }
  });
}
```

with `spawn_async` being:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
std::experimental::future<decltype(std::declval<Func>()())>
spawn_async(Func&& func) {
  std::experimental::promise<decltype(std::declval<Func>()())> p;
  auto res = p.get_future();
  std::thread t(
    [p = std::move(p), f = std::decay_t<Func>(func)]() mutable {
      try {
        p.set_value_at_thread_exit(f());
      } catch(...) {
        p.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
      }
    });
  t.detach();
  return res;
}
```

However, according to the author, this is still bad because "*If the function calls to the backend block internally because they’re waiting for
messages to cross the network or for a database operation to complete, then you’re not done yet. You may have split the task into its individual parts, but they’re still blocking calls, so you still get blocked threads. What you need is for the backend calls to return futures that become ready when the data is ready, without blocking any threads*"

[3] So the final piece of code ends up being:

```cpp
std::experimental::future<void> process_login(
 const std::string& username, const std::string& password)
{
  return backend.async_authenticate_user(username,password).then(
    [](std::experimental::future<user_id> id) {
      return backend.async_request_current_info(id.get());
    }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_data> info_to_display) {
      try {
        update_display(info_to_display.get());
      } catch(std::exception& e) {
        display_error(e);
      }
    });
}
```

where the `backend` functions return an `experimental::future`.

So here are all the doubts.

- I don't understand what the difference between [1] and [2] snippets is.  Sure [1] single tasks (such as `backend.request_current_info`) might block, but in [2] the same task might block as well, and then() will only proceed when the task before ended.
- How exactly is the thread NOT bloked in the last snippet, [3], given that `future`'s `.then()` function only proceeds when the previous task is done?

Answer (score 0):

I also could not understand the first question, especially for the reason that the author admitted later that:

"If the function calls to the backend block internally because they’re waiting for messages to cross the network or for a database operation to complete, then you’re not done yet."

For the second question, maybe I have got the idea of it.

I think that the author wanted to mean that `authenticate_user` is like a `while` loop which keeps checking if the network response has come, while `async_authenticate_user` just pass a `promise` object to some network framework, which ticks every frame and call `promise.set_value` when the waited response arrives. So the latter implementation will not block the thread any more.